# How to launch a command at the startup of only the very first shell of an X session?

Tags: x11, zsh, session

I am running Gnome on Pop-OS! 20.04.

I am using `terminator` and `zsh` shell. I want to launch `fortune` only the first time I use zsh shell in a X session.

I have tried those kind of things in `.zshrc`:

```
### count the lines of
ps -ax | grep zsh
ps -ax | grep /zsh

###
[ -z "$(pidof zsh)" ] && fortune
```

PS: I had hard times finding appropriate tags for this quesion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the precise requirement “once per X session”, the most natural place to store the information that this has already been done in the current X session is in the state of the X server. There isn't really an intended place for custom global data on an X server, but there's a place for custom global configuration which can be changed at any time, which is close enough for the purpose here: [X resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources). The command line tool to manipulate X resources is [`xrdb`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrdb.1.html).

Beware that `xrdb` is quirky and the X.org implementation has extremely long-standing bugs. You probably don't want to use `xrdb -load` (which removes all previously loaded configuration as documented) or `xrdb -remove` (which removes all previously loaded configuration, unlike what it's supposed to do).

Untested code for your `.zshrc`:

```
if [[ -n ${DISPLAY:+set} ]] && whence xrdb >/dev/null; then
  if xrdb -query | grep -q '^pietrodito\.session\.ran-fortune:.*true'; then
    fortune
    xrdb -merge <<<'pietrodito.session.ran-fortune: true'
  fi
fi
```

To unset the option for testing:

```
xrdb -load <(xrdb -query | grep -v '^pietrodito\.session\.ran-fortune:)
```

Note that this is not atomic. `fortune` may run multiple times if you start zsh instances at almost exactly the same time.

Answer (score 2):

This one will launch `fortune` only if there is no other zsh shell running:

```
[[ "$(pidof zsh)" == *' '* ]] || fortune
```

Comment: Wouldn't this run `fortune` every time you start `zsh` while no other `zsh` process is running, regardless of whether it is the first time in the current graphical session or not?

Comment: Exactly! But it is better than at every shell opening...